# ASP.Net MVC 4 layout changing

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to convert an html template to ASP.Net MVC 4 project. Bbut i have run in an problem. Then opening the `localHost:11062/` site everything looks prefect[image: Se here]. But if i try same address just calling the controller and action direct `localHost:11062/StartMenu/Index`, which should be the same, but it's not[image: Se here]. For me it looks like the css file isent loaded correct. But if it wasent the start site should not look different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you have hardcoded the url to some of your CSS files, just like this:

```
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of using an url helper:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Of course the same is true for all static resources such as javascript, images, ...

You should never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. Always use url helpers when dealing with urls.

Also if you are referencing some static resources (such as images) in your CSS file, don't forget that they should be relative to the location of the CSS file.

You might easily see this in the `Net` tab of a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug where you would get 404 errors for the corresponding resource.

Comment: Maybee it's the javascript. I can see that there are on javascript file. Where in that file its calling the rest of the javascript files. Like so (function() {
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>');
}).call(this);

Comment: Yes, this definitely seems wrong. You have hardcoded the path to the javascript file instead of using an url helper. Also `document.write` should be avoided.

Comment: But what to change it with, in an javascript file ore CSS file??

Comment: In your layout you could have a dynamic, global javascript variable pointing to the root of your site: `<script type="text/javascript">var siteRoot = '@Url.Content("~/")';</script>`. Now inside your javascript file you could use this variable to generate urls. Or even better, directly generate the path to the javascript file in question: `<script type="text/javascript">var siteRoot = '@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js")';</script>`. But I repeat once again: don't use `document.write` in javascript. That's a very obsolete method. I see that you are using jquery....

Comment: ... so why not take advantage of it? And more specifically the `$.getScript()` method is exactly designed for this purpose - dynamically include a javascript file into the DOM.